# I am confused on nth term rules / sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

So ...... I am really bad at maths and I need a bit of help please can you help me complete this and tell me answers

The nth rearm of a sequence is n(n-1)

1.what are the first four terms

I don't understand what n (n-1) stands for

Comment: To get the $n^{th}$ term, let's call it $a_n$, you simply plug $n$ into your expression.  Thus $a_0=0\times (0-1)=0$, $a_1=1\times (1-1)=0$, $a_2=2\times (2-1)=2$ and so on.

Comment: Try substituing a value for $n$ in the given information, e.g. for $n=7$ you get "The 7th term is $7(7-1)$.

Comment: The $n^{th}$ term can be thought of as the "whatever$^{th}$" term. If you want the $4^{th}$ term, you replace $n$ by $4$ in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ denote your sequence.   The $nth$ term, $a_n$ is given by 
$a_n = n(n-1)$.

For example, what is your first term?
$a_1 = 1(1-1) = 0$.  Second?  $a_2 = 2(2-1) = 2(1) = 2$.

Can you find the third and the fourth?